# How to sort an array values in `desc` in computed?

Tags: sorting, ember.js, ember-data

I have an model value, when i do the each iteration it works fine.

```
<ul>
    <li>See here : </li>
    {{#each selectedCreditCard.balances.tenures as |balance|}}
    <li>Balances is : {{balance}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But I require to sorted the value by `desc` way. so I use the `computed` method to do the `desc` the array.

```
sortTenuresBy:['desc'],
sortedTenures: Ember.computed.sort('selectedCreditCard.balances.tenures', 'sortTenuresBy'),
maxTenure:Ember.computed(function(){
return this.get('sortedTenures').get('firstObject');
```

But getting error as like this:

```
Assertion Failed: When using @each to observe the array 3,8,12,24, the array must return an object
```

how to fix this? please help me

Comment: The main problem is I don't have the Key for values. it's just a raw array like [1,2,3,4]

Comment: If you want to get `max`, you can use [Ember.computed.max](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/namespaces/Ember.computed/methods/max?anchor=max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [API](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/namespaces/Ember.computed/methods/sort?anchor=sort) definition for `Ember.computed.sort`; it requires a property key (that is `selectedCreditCard.balances.tenures` in your case) and a sort definition (that is `sortTenuresBy` in your case). However, if you look at the examples provided; the sort definition must be either a plain property name or a property name followed by sort type such as `name:desc` or `key:asc` and so on. In summary; it is not possible to use `Ember.computed.sort` for plain arrays as in your case. I admit the API documentation is vague.

For your case; you have to either write the computed property as a function; which is what you do not want I suppose; because it is the common way; or you can make use of the following [addon](https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-awesome-macros). What is great about `ember-awesome-macros` is you can nest the provided computed macros.

If you look at [API](https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-awesome-macros#arraysort) for `array.sort`; it says "combines the functionality of both Array.prototype.sort() and Ember.computed.sort". Hence we can use this one. You want the array to be sorted in descending; I suppose something like the following

```
sortTenuresBy: array.reverse(array.sort('selectedCreditCard.balances.tenures'))
```

should work.